# Regular expression - replace specific string based on different string condition

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I am dealing with a replacement of many lines of code.
What I need to do is to replace specific string based on various conditions.
Here is the string:

```
private IWebElement UserList_Link { get; set; }
```

I need to replace `{ get; set; }` with different string e.g. `=something`
It is obvious to put into search `{ get; set; }` and replace all. But I need it only for lines that contains `private IWebElement`.

So the final string needs to look like this:

```
private IWebElement UserList_Link = element;
```

I tried regex with positive look ahead like this, but it is taking word before curly bracket:

> (?<=IWebElement \w)(.*)

I am not sure how to do it. Can you please help me somebody out?

Comment: Try `(?<=IWebElement\s+\w+\s+){[^{}]*}`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dIWebElement%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%5cs%2b%29%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d&i=private+IWebElement+UserList_Link+%7b+get%3b+set%3b+%7d&r=%3d+element). Also, `(\sIWebElement\s+\w+\s+){[^{}]*}` => `$1= element` will work. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5csIWebElement%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%5cs%2b%29%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d&i=private+IWebElement+UserList_Link+%7b+get%3b+set%3b+%7d&r=%241%3d+element).

Comment: Well it is good I like it, but tell me on the other hand why https://regex101.com/ evaluates it as a pattern error?

Comment: regex101 does not support .NET regex.

Comment: So, does `(?<=IWebElement\s+\w+\s+){[^{}]*}` do what you need?

Comment: Yes I do. Thank you so much! I did not know it that regex101 does not support .NET regex. Gesus. ok good!

Comment: Can you please describe this second pattern? `{[^{}]*}` Does it mean to select everything except '{}'?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55724898/3832970).

Comment: Is anything unclear? Or do you need more help with this?

Comment: Well I have another issue with different string :) Trying to replace last three chars in here: `protected IList<IWebElement> SelectionItems => TryFindOne(By.CssSelector("ul li a.jstree-anchor")];` using (?<=<IWebElement>\s+\w+\s+)(\)\]\;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191971/discussion-between-michal-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Why not use `(<IWebElement>.*)\)];` (or `(<IWebElement>\s+\w+\s.*)\)];`) and replace with `$1`?

Comment: How it could work? What is referred by $1 in this case? It is so complex. Actually your suggestion works.

Comment: I wrote about that in my answer. `(...)` is a capturing group. `$1` refers to the value captured within that group.

Comment: How to make it? I am in for U!

Comment: I modified the comment above with the links to how this is done on SO

Comment: Is that now correct?

Comment: Thanks. Marking an answer as accepted, you let others know it works best for you. To say thank you, you may also click the UP arrow beside each answer that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 search and replace dialog, you may use

**Find**: `(?<=IWebElement\s+\w+\s+){[^{}]*}`
**Replace**: `= element`

See [this .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dIWebElement%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%5cs%2b%29%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2A%7d&i=private+IWebElement+UserList_Link+%7b+get%3b+set%3b+%7d&r=%3d+element).

Here, `(?<=IWebElement\s+\w+\s+)` is a positive lookbehind that matches a location in a string that is immediately preceded with `IWebElement`, 1+ whitespaces, 1+ word chars, 1+ whitespaces. It is of variable width and works with limited regex engines. Then, `{[^{}]*}` matches and consumes `{`, 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`.

You may  also use a more common regex without a variable width lookbehind:

**Find**: `(IWebElement\s+\w+\s+){[^{}]*}`
**Replace**: `$1= element`

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5csIWebElement%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%5cs%2b%29%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2A%7d&i=private+IWebElement+UserList_Link+%7b+get%3b+set%3b+%7d&r=%241%3d+element).

A [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(IWebElement%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B)%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%7D) graph:

[image]

Here, `(IWebElement\s+\w+\s+)` is a capturing group with ID = 1 and you may refer to its contents with a `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern. If you have a digit after `$1`, use `${1}` unambiguous form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookahead

```
^(?=private IWebElement.*)(.*){ get; set; }$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=private IWebElement.*)` - Positive lookahead to make `private IWebElement` must in match
- `(.*)` - Match any thing except new line ( captured group )
- `$` - End of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/SEnUnU/1/)

Comment: I tried in Visual Studio 2017 and it cannot find  the string to replace :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `regex`:

```
(private IWebElement.*?) ({ get; set; })
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jVRzhw/1)

#### Replacing using C#:

```
string str = "private IWebElement UserList_Link { get; set; }";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(private IWebElement.*?) ({ get; set; })", "$1 = element");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

**`$1`** means the first group of the regex match.

Comment: Tried in Visual Studio 2017 and unfortunately it replaces all the line which is not what I wanted :(

Comment: Hmmm that's quite weird... What do you mean with "all the line"? This should replace all the lines that match the regex above.

Comment: Line 'private IWebElement UserList_Link { get; set; }' is replaced with 'something'

Comment: You should use `$1 = something`

Comment: Ok, my mistake. It is valid and works like a charm. Sorry.